# Calculating the total from transactional db where values are negative and positive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a question which may have a simple solution that I'm missing.

I have a transactional database that I must use to build a query to calculate how much members have spent in the last X time period using their member card.
Values can be positive when there's a return or when they reload their card. I calculate the sum of values that are negative AND when the `ArticleID` is 5033.

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║    ID   ║      MemberNumber ║ ArticleID ║ Quantity ║   Price   ║ TotalPrice ║         PurchaseDate        ║             PurchaseDateTime ║   AssociateID ║ PaymentTypeID ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1174030 ║             45143 ║        -1 ║        1 ║     74,00 ║   74,00    ║     2012-11-16 00:00:00.000 ║ 40:24.0                      ║            72 ║             1 ║
║ 1174028 ║             45143 ║      5033 ║        1 ║    -74,00 ║  -74,00    ║     2012-11-16 00:00:00.000 ║ 35:33.0                      ║             7 ║            15 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

In the above example, someone bought something for 74 but then returned it a few minutes later. The ArticleID isn't helpful here since `-1` is used for other things as well. In this case, the total should be 0.

Therefore,

```
SELECT SUM(TOTALPRICE) 
FROM   TABLEX 
WHERE  CONDITIONY
```

isn't working because there are other ArticleIDs that I'm filtering out as well.

Comment: Since a member could buy 2 different articles for the same price and return either one of them, it seems to me to be impossible to do what you're asking. Is there any way to connect the original transaction and the cancellation?

Comment: I don't see a way to connect the original txn and the refund. Would it be possible to do this by date? We do issue refunds in unusual circumstances on a different date but most refunds are on the same date.

Comment: Technically, yes but logically this would not be a good idea as I stated previously. By doing this you're asking for problems.